# In App Purchase Crashes on [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]

Tags: iphone, crash, in-app-purchase, nszombie

My In-App-Purchases work. I present a ModalView with a "Buy" UIButton. You click the button and the In App Purchase goes through the process. You can even do it several times in a row.

The problem occurs if you open the Modal View, then close the Modal View (using a UITabBarButtonItem), then reopen the Modal View and tap the "Buy" button. The app crashes and I get an NSZombie that reads

> *** -[InAppPurchaseManager respondsToSelector:]: message sent to
>   deallocated instance 0x1c7ad0

The NSZombie points to line 160 in the .m file. I have marked it with comments.

I got the original code from this page: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

I have been struggling with this for many days now... any help would be awesome.

Here is the .h

```
//
//  InAppPurchaseManager.h
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification"
#define kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification @"kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification"

#define kInAppPurchaseCreditProductId @"com.myname.app.iap"

@interface InAppPurchaseManager : UIViewController <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
{
    SKProduct *productID;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;

 IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *closeButton;
 IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
 IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProduct *productID;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *closeButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;


// public methods
-(void)loadStore;
-(BOOL)canMakePurchases;
-(void)purchaseCredit;

-(void)requestInAppPurchaseData;
-(void)buyButtonAction:(id)sender;
-(void)closeButtonAction:(id)sender;
-(void)updateButtonStatus:(NSString *)status;

@end
```

Here is the .m

```
// InAppPurchaseManager.m

#import "InAppPurchaseManager.h"

@implementation InAppPurchaseManager

@synthesize productID;
@synthesize productsRequest;

@synthesize closeButton;
@synthesize buyButton;
@synthesize testLabel;


- (void)dealloc {

 [productID release];
 //[productsRequest release];

 [closeButton release];
 [buyButton release];
 [testLabel release];

    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 [closeButton release];
 closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(closeButtonAction:)];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;

 [self loadStore];

 self.navigationItem.title = @"Credits";


}

-(void)closeButtonAction:(id)sender { 
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(void)buyButtonAction:(id)sender {

 if([self canMakePurchases]) {
  [self updateButtonStatus:@"OFF"];

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(requestInAppPurchaseData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

 } else {
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithString:@"Your account settings do not allow for In App Purchases."] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alertView show];
  [alertView release];  
 }

}


-(void)updateButtonStatus:(NSString *)status {

 if ([status isEqual:@"OFF"]) {
  closeButton.enabled = NO;
  buyButton.enabled = NO;
  buyButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 } else {
  closeButton.enabled = YES;
  buyButton.enabled = YES;
  buyButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
 }

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods


//
// call this method once on startup
//
- (void)loadStore
{

    // restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

}


- (void)requestInAppPurchaseData
{
 NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:kInAppPurchaseCreditProductId];

    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}



- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;


    productID = [products count] == 1 ? [[products objectAtIndex:0] retain] : nil;
    if (productID)
    {
  /*
   NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , productID.localizedTitle);
   NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , productID.localizedDescription);
   NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , productID.price);
   NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , productID.productIdentifier);
   */

  NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *currentCredits = ([standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"currentCredits"]) ? [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"currentCredits"] : @"0";

  testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentCredits];
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
  testLabel.text = @"Try Again Later.";
    }

    // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
    [productsRequest release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];

 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(purchaseCredit) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}


//
// call this before making a purchase
//
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

//
// kick off the upgrade transaction
//
- (void)purchaseCredit
{

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseCreditProductId];

 // *********************************************************************************************************
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]; // <--- This is where the NSZombie Appears *************
 // *********************************************************************************************************

}

#pragma -
#pragma Purchase helpers

//
// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
//
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
 if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseCreditProductId])
    {
        // save the transaction receipt to disk
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"InAppPurchaseTransactionReceipt" ];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

}

//
// enable pro features
//
- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId
{
 if ([productId isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseCreditProductId])
    {        
  // Increment currentCredits
  NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *currentCredits = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"currentCredits"];
  int newCreditCount = [currentCredits intValue] + 1;
  [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newCreditCount] forKey:@"currentCredits"];

  testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newCreditCount];

    }

}

//
// removes the transaction from the queue and posts a notification with the transaction result
//
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{

    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
    if (wasSuccessful)
    {
        // send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
    else
    {
        // send out a notification for the failed transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }


 [self updateButtonStatus:@"ON"];

}

//
// called when the transaction was successful
//
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{

 [self updateButtonStatus:@"OFF"];

 [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
 [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];

}

//
// called when a transaction has been restored and and successfully completed
//
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

//
// called when a transaction has failed
//
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
   // error!
        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
    }
    else
    {
   // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }

 [self updateButtonStatus:@"ON"];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods

//
// called when the transaction status is updated
//
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The error message indicates a message is being sent to a deallocated instance of `InAppPurchaseManager`, which is your class. And it's happening after you open the view (creating an instance), close the view (releasing an instance), then opening the view again (creating a second instance). And the problem is happening within the `addPayment:` call. This indicates that the framework still has a handle on your old, released instance, and is trying to send it a message.

You give the framework a handle to your object in loadStore, when you call

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

I don't see anywhere where you remove `self` as an observer. Objects that send out notifications usually do not retain their observers, since doing so can create a retain cycle and/or a memory leak.

In your `dealloc` code you need to cleanup and call `removeTransactionObserver:`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: That was it... [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

Comment: @benzado: I have an ARC enabled project and I am facing the same issue. I have ensured that I implement removeTransactionObsserver: but the problem doesn't go.

Comment: @mvb I was going to suggest you ask a new question, but I see you already have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968746/in-app-purchase-view-controller-crash-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance

Comment: @benzado Thanks! I am using ARC and this worked for me: 
- (void)dealloc {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}

Comment: @benzado added the removeTransactionObserver:self in dealloc but still crashing!!

Comment: you must cancel request and works. Read my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37281949/4693765

Answer (score 0):

I think observers added using addTransactionObserver are apparently weak references - not strong ones, which would explain this. I've made a simple test:

```
// bad code below:
// the reference is weak so the observer is immediately destroyed
addTransactionObserver([[MyObserver alloc] init]);
...
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]; // crash
```

And got the same crash even without calling removeTransactionObserver.
The solution in my case was to simply keep a strong reference to the observer:

```
@property (strong) MyObserver* observer;
....
self.observer = [[MyObserver alloc] init];
addTransactionObserver(observer);
```