# In-App Purchases: Crash when view disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My application has a tabbar that contains 4 view controllers. The third view controller contains a "store in-app purchases". In this controller I use an object that manages in-app purchases (product request, purchase, transaction etc...) that allow me to get and show price description ecc.

The problem is: If I change tabs while the request started the app crashes sometimes, but not always.

I've to cancel the request in viewDidDisappear?
[productsRequest cancel] this code crashes.

Comment: I have the same problem. It´s a apple bug because they implements force delegate.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
To fix it cancel request and all be fine.

```
var request: SKProductsRequest! //global to cancel when disappear
//request products when you want (viewDidLoad for example)
   request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
```

And when disapear viewcontroller:

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        request.delegate = nil;
        request.cancel()
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has probably nothing to do with in-app purchase. Somewhere in your code you're sending a message to an object which has been released. Running the analyzer can help you find the bug, but it may not be necessary this time. If [productsRequest cancel] crashes, then probably productsRequest has too low retain count.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `TransactionObserver` while your `viewDidDisappear`:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

If you go back from the Inapp viewcontroller to another viewcontroller,then

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]removeTransactionObserver:self];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```