# BAD_ACCESS with SKProductRequest

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, exc-bad-access

Ok so basically I have been stuck 2 days in the same, and it appears that anybadoy has my problem, so if anybody can help I would be very thankful!!!!

I have my inappPurchaseManager.h

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification  @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"

@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>
{
SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
} 
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData;
@end
```

then in my .m I have

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{


NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:kMyCompany ];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;

[productsRequest start];
NSLog(@"a");
}
```

after this my app crashes... with EXC_BAD ACCESS..

I am calling requestProUpgradeProductData from another class

I am using ARC

Thanks A lot!!!

Comment: how do you handle the delegate methods? (SKProductsRequestDelegate)

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to guess something when you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Try to turn on NSZombieEnabled.
[How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)

Comment: So i enabled Zombies, and the result was:

 *** -[InAppPurchaseManager respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x948a370

Comment: I think you can find answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150926/in-app-purchase-crashes-on-skpaymentqueue-defaultqueue-addpaymentpayment